# How to redirect www.site.appspot.com to non-www?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

How to redirect from www to non-www site to google cloud?
My Yaml file

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: proxy.app
```

Comment: Sorry, would you kindly elaborate? While I can understand to a degree what you mean by "how to redirect from www to no-www site to google cloud", I don't have the whole picture so it's a little hard to provide an answer. Could you sort of indicate the structure/path of what you're trying to accomplish? As well as possibly the contents of `proxy.app`? That way we have an [mre] from which to start.

Comment: hi!
Thank you for answering my question.
I need my site, which after deployment received such an address https://www.mysitename.appspot.com/, redirected to the same site but only without "www." 

So, I need to have such a redirect:
https://www.mysitename.appspot.com -> https://mysitename.appspot.com/

Comment: Oh, I see. As you may have noticed from the url formatting in your text, the "www." is obviated to a degree when it comes to URLs. That is because "www." serves as a prefix to establish that you are connecting to the internet, rather than a server or service within your LAN. As an example: "google.com" will redirect you to "www.google.com" in your browser, in fact, anything you input within your browser's navigation bar that doesn't start with either "C://" or "\" will be taken as a url, and pre-pended with "www." if it does not have that already. Your app doesn't have "www.", it's just online

Comment: My initial understanding was that you were referring to the "www" folder, which is often the name of the folder serving the html documents for the webpage within lots of frameworks, such as Laravel, as an example. I apologize for my confusion